# Make month in date field to be non case sensitive

Tags: c#, angularjs, validation

I have a datepicker in angular application. The format given for the date is:

```
'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'
```

But now the thing is if we enter month in lower case it works fine but when we enter month in upper case it gives validation message of incorrect format.
For eg:- **23-jan-2013** is a valid date where as **23-JAN-2013** is invalid.

Here is the html:

```
<input
  type="text"
  datetime-picker={{format.dateTimePickerSec}}
  ng-model="model.ArrivalDateTime"
  is-open="ctrl.open.date1"
  name="arrivalDateTime"
  id="arrivalDateTime"
  @*min-date="ctrl.minimum.date1"*@
  timepicker-options="ctrl.timeOptions"
  clear-text="clear"
  enable-time="true"
  ng-maxlength="20"
  limit-to="20" />
```

and value for  dateTimePickerSec: 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'

Is there any solution that both are considered valid scenario

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: done please check n help

Comment: I am looking into it, in the while you can set input type="date"

Comment: do you have form validations ?

Comment: No normal validation.. we are using ui.datepicker

Comment: In my opinion you should go with this simple and easy date picker : https://codepen.io/tutorialab/pen/JDxkn 

because angularjs update can make difference in your work.